# My append function for the list isn't working. How do I fix it?

Tags: python

I'm making a game with python and I want to make it so that, there are items added into the backpack. I chose to use append but I don't know why it isn't working. Here is the code:

```
while True:
direction = input("\nEnter your letter (R, L, F, P, B): ").upper()
if direction == "L":
    print(images.number)
elif direction == "F":
    password = input("\nEnter the 6-letter password: ").upper()
    if password == "CHANGE":
        score = score + 30
        print(f"Congratulations on solving this puzzle. You have gained 30 points, nice to know you can listen to instructions. Slowly open up the box, to get the key and vial. Put the vial in your bag and head to the door to unlock it.")
    else:
        print("That is wrong, can you look at the instructions properly!")
        print(direction)
elif direction == "P":
    print(score)
elif direction == "B":
    if score == 50:
        backpack.append("Vial of Virus")
        print(f"Your backpack contains:")
        for y in backpack:
            print(y)
    else:
        print(f"Your backpack contains:")
        for x in backpack:
            print(x)
elif direction == "R":
    if score == 50:
        print("You insert the key into the keyhole and turn it. The door creaks open, and you slowly enter into the last and final room.")
        break
    else:
        print("Find the key to the door!")
        print(direction)
```

here is the output I'm getting, there should be another item (Vial of Virus) instead of only those 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cXPS.png)

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Your code will not reproduce the issue you are describing, it will throw a `NameError` because it refers to variables you have not defined.

Comment: I assume you have backpack and score defined globally outside your while loop?

Comment: What is your expected output and what is the output you're actually getting?

Comment: try add `strip()` to `.upper()`

Comment: yes both backpack and score is defined, sorry i forgot to copy paste that part of the code.

Comment: what do i do with strip() and .upper()?

Comment: `.upper().strip()`

Comment: When you type "B" is your score still 50? Add a print statement to check. Maybe somehow the score is getting re-set?

Answer (score 0):

The append function works in this example you've given assuming that score is equal to 50 when the user inputs B. The only reason that the append function doesn't work is if the score is not equal to 50.

```
Enter your letter (R, L, F, P, B): B
Your backpack contains:
Vial of Virus

Enter your letter (R, L, F, P, B):
```

Code that made the above terminal output:

```py
score = 50
backpack = []
while True:
    direction = input("\nEnter your letter (R, L, F, P, B): ").upper()
    if direction == "L":
        print(images.number)
    elif direction == "F":
        password = input("\nEnter the 6-letter password: ").upper()
        if password == "CHANGE":
            score = score + 30
            print(f"Congratulations on solving this puzzle. You have gained 30 points, nice to know you can listen to instructions. Slowly open up the box, to get the key and vial. Put the vial in your bag and head to the door to unlock it.")
        else:
            print("That is wrong, can you look at the instructions properly!")
            print(direction)
    elif direction == "P":
        print(score)
    elif direction == "B":
        if score == 50:
            backpack.append("Vial of Virus")
            print(f"Your backpack contains:")
            for y in backpack:
                print(y)
        else:
            print(f"Your backpack contains:")
            for x in backpack:
                print(x)
    elif direction == "R":
        if score == 50:
            print("You insert the key into the keyhole and turn it. The door creaks open, and you slowly enter into the last and final room.")
            break
        else:
            print("Find the key to the door!")
            print(direction)
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: lol u right, idk y i would do that